# How to create a PHP function

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I convert the code below into a PHP function that works.

Here is my original code.

```
if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    $cat_name = strip_tags(filter_var($_GET['cat'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

So far I got this for the function.

```
function cat(){
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
        $cat_name = strip_tags(filter_var($_GET['cat'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: and what is not ok with your function?

Comment: @Tudor Constantin its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the sanitized value or `null` if `$_GET['cat']` is not set. When you call this function, you would need to check if the return value is `null`.

```
function get_cat() {
    $cat_name = null;
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
        $cat_name = strip_tags(filter_var($_GET['cat'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
    return $cat_name;
}
```

Comment: how would I call the function?

Comment: Just call it via `get_cat()`, or `$cat = get_cat()` to save the value.

Comment: this aint working I get the following error Undefined variable: cat_name

Comment: This works for me. (Note that I left out the opening brace on the first line. Fixed now.) How are you calling the function?

Comment: If one these answers works for you, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
function get_cat($GET) 
    $cat_name = null;
    if(isset($GET['cat'])) {
        $cat_name = strip_tags(filter_var($GET['cat'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
    return $cat_name;
}
```

And to call it, just do:

```
$cat = get_cat($_GET);
```

With this, the `get_cat` function is encapsulated (doesn't depend on external vars).

Just my 2 cents. Hope this helps. Cheers